# How do I do undo chmod /usr/bin

Tags: permissions, chmod

For some reason I was messing around and did `chmod -x /usr/bin/*` (no idea what I was thinking)

Is there a way to fix this, because at the moment nothing is executable

Comment: boot from live CD, mount your partition, do the reverse

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/*
```

In case your chmod binary is in /usr/bin you could try to sftp a copy of the file in from another host.

Or boot from live CD, mount the right filesystem, and `chmod +x` the file.